# How to loop and delete stop words from a folder

Tags: python, nlp

I am currently working on the task of deleting stop words. This code can be run, but I would like to ask how to change it into a loop statement, that is, loop to extract stop words in a folder instead of a single file. It might be the "file1.... this statement", but I don't know how to change it. The code is attached as follows, Thanks!

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
file1 = open(
    r"D:\1.1 SEC EDGAR年报源文件 (10Q_10KA_10QA)\2001\QTR1\20010102_10-K-A_edgar_data_1024302_0001092388-00-500453.txt")
line = file1.read()
words = word_tokenize(line)
words_witout_stop_words = ["" if word in stop_words else word for word in words]
new_words = " ".join(words_witout_stop_words).strip()
appendFile = open(
    r"D:\1.1 SEC EDGAR年报源文件 (10Q_10KA_10QA)\2001\QTR1\20010102_10-K-A_edgar_data_1024302_0001092388-00-500453.txt", 'w')
appendFile.write(new_words)
appendFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix for this is to get all the files in the folder and run the code on them.

I have mentioned the whole code here:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import os

path = r"D:\1.1 SEC EDGAR年报源文件 (10Q_10KA_10QA)\2001\QTR1\""
files = os.listdir(path)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for i in files:
    file1 = open(path + i)
    line = file1.read()
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_witout_stop_words = ["" if word in stop_words else word for word in words]
    new_words = " ".join(words_witout_stop_words).strip()
    appendFile = open(path + i, 'w')
    appendFile.write(new_words)
    appendFile.close()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code! but when I run this it came up with an error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ......", I have such problems before and failed to solve it till now. Do you know how to fix it? thank you!

Comment: What is the full error? which file wasn't found